Ball not rolling
In Apple visionOS I've made a ground:
if let floor = scene.findEntity(named: "Sol")
{
    floor.components[PhysicsBodyComponent.self] = .init(
        massProperties: .default,
        material: .generate( staticFriction: 1, dynamicFriction: 0.5, restitution: 0),
        mode: .static)
    floor.generateCollisionShapes( recursive: false)
    floor.components.set( ImageBasedLightComponent(source: .single( environmentLight!)))
    floor.components.set( ImageBasedLightReceiverComponent( imageBasedLight: floor))
}


and a ball:
if let sphere = scene.findEntity(named: "Boule_Chrome")
{
    Set_Entity_Params( entity: sphere, mass: 0.70, friction: kBoules_Friction, rebond: 0.0005, ralentissement: 1)
    sphere.components.set( ImageBasedLightComponent(source: .single( environmentLight!)))
    sphere.components.set( ImageBasedLightReceiverComponent( imageBasedLight: sphere))
}
.

..
func Set_Entity_Params( entity: Entity, mass: Float, friction: Float, rebond: Float, ralentissement: Float, mode: PhysicsBodyMode = .dynamic)
{
    entity.components.set( InputTargetComponent())// Permet d'etre saisisable à la main
    entity.components.set( GroundingShadowComponent(castsShadow: true))

    var spherePhysics = PhysicsBodyComponent( massProperties: .init(mass: mass), material: .generate(staticFriction: friction, dynamicFriction: friction, restitution: rebond), mode: mode)
    spherePhysics.isRotationLocked = (x:false, y:false, z:false)
    spherePhysics.isContinuousCollisionDetectionEnabled = true
    spherePhysics.angularDamping = 0.9 
    spherePhysics.linearDamping = ralentissement 
    entity.components.set( spherePhysics)
}


To launch the ball on the ground, I just apply a linear velocity:
sphere.components[PhysicsMotionComponent.self]?.linearVelocity = SIMD3<Float>(0, 0, -7.8)

All is perfect, the ball is launched, touch the ground and move on the ground, that's perfect. Except the ball doesn't roll on the ground, it slides
Could someone help me to have the ball rolling on the ground?

Perhaps you want to set the angularVelocity as well as the linearVelocity ?

already tryed, but without result :'(

Ok guys i've founded the solution : If I'm using a simple sphere primitive shape form it does that, BUT, if I use a USDA sphere (from a 3D software) it roll !!!!!!!

angularVelocity.z instance property, along with the related settings, does the trick:
var angularVelocity: SIMD3<Float>

The main reason why a RealityKit's sphere primitive does not work, but the USDA sphere from the RCP scene does, is that the model must contain a CollisionComponent.

This component holds the entity’s data related to participating in the scene’s physics simulation. It is also used to calculate collision queries, raycasts, and convex shape casts.

